# How to display contents present in zip file to windows form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am using windows form. In which we select a zip file from our system. And after selection of that file if we click "Show Content" then contents should b displayed in a TextBox.

How is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the library called DotNetZip at  http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples

The library have a class ZipEntry with property FileName (http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/)  iterate the filenames from the Zip as shown in example of the first url

Hope this helps ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source library to read zip-files (get it via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib) Here you can find samples of reading the contents of a zip-file:

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx